# Sort file by column

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting

I'm trying to sort a file that looks like this

```
MarkerName      Allele1 Allele2 Weight  Zscore  P-value Direction^Mrs217377     t       c       6806    1.121   0.2625  +++^Mrs4668077
  a       g       6806    -0.038  0.9696  --+^Mrs16855496 a       g       4106    -0.092  0.9268  ??-^Mrs217386   a       g       6806
    0.814   0.4158  +++^Mrs2075070  a       g       6806    -0.699  0.4844  --+^Mrs10187002 a       t       4106    0.099   0.9208  ??+^Mrs12785983 t       c       6806    -1.092  0.2747  +--^Mrs1100405  t       c       6806    -0.872  0.3831  +--^Mrs12155014 t       c
       6806    0.081   0.9358  ++-^Mrs2287619  t       c       6806    -2.221  0.02632 ---^M
```

After the seventh white space there is a `^M` character instead of a simple newline. I'm not exactly sure how to deal with it or whether I can just ignore it.
I'm trying to sort each line by the P-Value (sixth) column.

Like this:

```
MarkerName      Allele1 Allele2 Weight  Zscore  P-value Direction
rs2287619       t       c       6806    -2.221  0.02632 ---
rs217377        t       c       6806    1.121   0.2625  +++
rs12785983      t       c       6806    -1.092  0.2747  +--
rs1100405       t       c       6806    -0.872  0.3831  +--
rs217386        a       g       6806    0.814   0.4158  +++
rs2075070       a       g       6806    -0.699  0.4844  --+
rs10187002      a       t       4106    0.099   0.9208  ??+
rs16855496      a       g       4106    -0.092  0.9268  ??-
rs4668077       a       g       6806    -0.038  0.9696  --+
```

So far I have this Perl code

```perl
use strict; 
use warnings;

die "Please specify a suitable text file\n" if (@ARGV != 1);
my ($infile) = @ARGV;

# create outputfile
my $outfile = "MetaAnalysis_Sorted.txt";

# create filehandles
open (my $in, " < $infile") or die "error reading $infile. $!";
open (my $out, " >> $outfile") or die "error creating $outfile. $!";


my @array;

while ( <$in> ) {
    chomp;  # removes newline
    push @array, $_;
    my @sorted = sort { (split '\s', $a)[5] <=> (split '\s', $b)[5] } @array;
    print $out join( "\n", @sorted )."\n\n";
}

close $in;
close $out;
```

I've tried converting the original file with `dos2unix` but it didn't work.

Comment: The carriage return character (0x0d) is shown as `^M` in Vim, if `fileformat=unix`. Are you viewing the file in Vim?

Comment: I'm viewing the file in Unix via the less command which usually separates carriage returns fine, should I not be worried for sorting if I'm viewing in a texteditor after?

Comment: `perl -pe 's/[\r\n]+/\n/' yourfile`

Comment: That would help, but I never recommend it to someone with an example command, because meddling with someone's source data is nasty.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you're using the `'\s'` literal instead of a regular
expression. You probably meant one or more spaces, i.e. `/s+/`.

Another issue is due to nun-numeric `P-value` passed to the `<=>` operator. I
suggest shifting the header off the array before calling `sort`.

Writing the output file should be performed outside of the `while (<$in>)` loop.

Also, I suggest skipping empty lines:

```
while (<$in>) {
    chomp;  #removes new line
    push @array, $_ if $_;
}
```

Here is a fixed version:

```
use strict; use warnings;

die "Please specify a suitable text file\n" if (@ARGV != 1);
my ($infile) = @ARGV;

#create outputfile
my $outfile = "MetaAnalysis_Sorted.txt";

#create filehandles
open (my $in, " < $infile") or die "error reading $infile. $!";
open (my $out, " >> $outfile") or die "error creating $outfile. $!";


my @array;
while (<$in>) {
    chomp;  #removes new line
    push @array, $_ if $_;
}


my $head = shift @array;
print $out "$head\n";

my @sorted = sort {
  (split /\s+/, $a)[5] <=> (split /\s+/, $b)[5];
} @array;
print $out join( "\n", @sorted )."\n\n";

close $in;
close $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

The sequence `^M` is used by many editors and text utilities to indicate Ctrl-M, or *carriage-return*. It looks like your file has been saved with just a carriage-return (CR) at the end of each line. That's very unusual. Linux uses just a linefeed (LF) while Windows uses the two characters CR LF. Only much older Macintosh systems used just CR

The regex character sequence `\R` can be very useful for this kind of file. It will match any one of LF, CR LF, or just CR. Unfortunately, you can't set the input line separator to a regex pattern -- it must be a literal string, so you will have to read the whole file into a single string and then use `split`

This program shows the idea, but it is hard to tell where any blank lines may appear in your sample data, and it is also artificially line-wrapped in the middle of records. This should work fine as long as you provide an unmodified data file for input

#### sort_by_col6.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @infile = do {
    local $/;
    split /\R/, <>;
};

local $\ = "\n";

print shift @infile;    # Print header line
print for sort { (split ' ', $a)[5] <=> (split ' ', $b) } @infile;
```

You will need to run it from the command prompt like this to redirect the output

```
$ perl sort_by_col6.pl my_input.txt > MetaAnalysis_Sorted.txt
```